# show / hide columns based on value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table

I'm still very inexperienced in javascript, nevertheless I'd like to try my hand at it and would be very happy to get some support. I have the following scenario:

I have a table, with several rows and 3 columns. Column 1 would be a name, column 2 would be a number (ID), column 3 would be a value.

I have a value (ID) in a WebApp that I would like to search for in the table in column 2 and would like to display only that row. What is the best way to start? What exact topics should I look at more closely to implement this? I would be very happy to receive an answer!

```
<div id="datatable" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr id="class1">
            <td>Person 1</td>
            <td>1234561</td>
            <td>800</td>
        </tr>
         <tr id="class1">
            <td>Person 2</td>
            <td>1234562</td>
            <td>1800</td>
        </tr>
         <tr id="class1">
            <td>Person 3</td>
            <td>1234563</td>
            <td>1400</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have already searched online for similar scripts, however this doesn't seem to be needed that often! So I would like to tackle this myself now. But how to start?

Comment: You have duplicate `id` attributes; this is invalid, as an `id` must be unique within the document. "*I have a value (ID) in a WebApp*" - please post your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should research DOM manipulation, so that you can actually
access and manipulate the values necessary. Also, you should research how to work with classes. A knowledge of loops is also needed. Finally, some understanding of HTML & CSS is necessary. All of this material is available on
W3schools, so check there.

EDIT: You didn't ask for the coded solution, which is why I'm not giving it.

Comment: Good to acquire knowledge on the foundations or basics, but I think this is a long way to reach the target

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `table` and loop through its `rows` with `forEach` and check if the `row.cells[1]` ( which is the ID cell ), its textContent start with `input` value, If not hide it with `display: none` and if it match show it with `display: table-row`

```js
const personTable = document.querySelector('table');
const tableRows = [...personTable.rows];
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const rows = tableRows.forEach(row => {
    const match = row.cells[1].textContent.trim().startsWith(value.trim())
    if (match) {
      row.style.display = 'table-row'
    } else {
      row.style.display = 'none'
    }
    
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="datatable" align="center">
    <table id="person-table">
        <tr id="class1">
            <td>Person 1</td>
            <td>1234561</td>
            <td>800</td>
        </tr>
         <tr id="class1">
            <td>Person 2</td>
            <td>1234562</td>
            <td>1800</td>
        </tr>
         <tr id="class1">
            <td>Person 3</td>
            <td>1234563</td>
            <td>1400</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many skills required it's quite hard to work out which without making it.

One thing that I have changed is your data from html into an array. I find arrays can be much easier to work with once you get your head around them — and how you can output them to HTML.

There are many ways to do this — that is important to know. There isn't really such thing as a "right" answer here.

- Arrays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- Query selectors — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- Functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions
- Input value https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp
- if statements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else
- Array filtering — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- Converting numbers to strings — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString
- String includes — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes
- Template literals — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
- Event listeners — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

```js
// Arrays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
const people = [
  { name: "Person 1", num: 1234, details: 800 },
  { name: "Person 2", num: 3456, details: 1800 },
  { name: "Person 3", num: 5678, details: 1400 }
];

// Query selectors — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
const tbody = document.querySelector("#tbody");
const searchBox = document.querySelector("#search-box");

// * Get the matching items
// Functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions
const selectList = () => {
  // * If nothing has been typed...
  // Input value https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp
  // if statements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else
  if(searchBox.value == ""){
    return people;
  }
  // Array filtering — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
  return people.filter(person => {
    // Converting numbers to strings — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString
    // String includes — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes
    return (person.num.toString()).includes(searchBox.value)
  })
}

// * Convert the array into data for the table
const getData = (found) => {
  // * If the result of our filter has no values
  if(found.length == 0){
    return `<tr>
      <td colspan="3">No results found</td>
    </tr>`
  }
  // Otherwise, create the rows
  // Template literals — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
  return found.map(person => `<tr id="class1">
            <td>${person.name}</td>
            <td>${person.num}</td>
            <td>${person.details}</td>
        </tr>`).join("\n");
}

// Called whenever the textbox changes
const render = () => {
  
  // Get the list
  const found = selectList();
  // Convert to html
  const data = getData(found);
  
  // Empty the body
  tbody.textContent = "";
  
  // Append the new data
  tbody.innerHTML = data;
}

// Event listeners — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
searchBox.addEventListener('input', render);
render();
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="search-box" />
</div>

<div>
  <div id="datatable" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Num</th>
        <th>Details</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <table>
        <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and not-necessarily dirty solution, check out https://datatables.net/ . This library solves most of your problems or desires with a table.

So you add the library first in your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Then in a script tag better after your , initialise Datatable on your table and select the table and add functionalities like this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#datatable').DataTable();
} );

$('#datatable').DataTable( {
    searching: true,
    paging: false
} );
```

Then little by little and depending on your learning hunger get your hands on learning the basics of JS, DOM, HTML, as other mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, a big thanks to you guys for your answers. This helps me a lot and I think I will not use the fastest solution, but fight my way through the Mimo JS section to expand my basic understanding. Your approaches are really great and thanks for the support! When I am ready I will post my solution here.

Comment: Hello and good luck with your future dev issue.
the "answer" you use here for your own question is not mean for the purpose you used it.
I will let you discover how stackoverflow work for next time

Comment: isn't an "answer" of the question, misunderstanding of stackoverflow ways